# printing cards with array values inside

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying to print the values of the array inside of cards, but for some reason the for loop isn't letting me print the cards

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as bs from 'react-bootstrap'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
import PRODUCTS from './products'
import ProductCard from './product-card'


function Center(props){


const product = Object.values(PRODUCTS)
product.map((product) => return(
   <bs.Container fluid ClassName = "p-0">

     <bs.Row noGutters style = {{padding: "6rem 0" }}>
            <bs.Col>


                for(var i= -; i< product.length; i++){

                   <ProductCard>


                  </ProductCard>
                }

          </bs.Col>


       </bs.Row>

     </bs.Container>

    )

    )


}

export default Center;
```

and here is the cards code:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as bs from 'react-bootstrap';
import { BrowserRouter  as Router , Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

function ProductCard(props) {

    return (


    <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
    <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
    <Card.Body>
      <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
      <Card.Text>

      </Card.Text>
      <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
    </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  )

}

export default ProductCard;
```

Comment: The first issue is that you need to wrap JS expressions inside JSX in curly-braces (`{ }`). Second, while the for-loop will run, it will not yield the result you want. To iterate an array, use `map()`, like you did at the start of your code.

Comment: Among the other things mentioned by @Chris, your `Center` functional component is not returning anything. I'm assuming it should return the array created by your product.map statement?

Comment: Do you have a sample of how  the `product` or `PRODUCTS` is like?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues with your code -

1) You aren't returning the result of the iterating through `product`.

2) You aren't properly nesting your JavaScript expressions within your JSX elements.

This is how it should be fixed:

```
function Center(props){
  const products = Object.values(PRODUCTS);

  return <>
    {
      products.map((product) => (
        <bs.Container fluid ClassName = "p-0">
          <bs.Row noGutters style = {{padding: "6rem 0" }}>
            <bs.Col>
            {
              product.map(() => <ProductCard />)
            }           
            </bs.Col>
          </bs.Row>
        </bs.Container>
      ))
   }
  </>
}
```

Comment: Your answer is generally correct, but there are a couple errors in your answer code: the products.map statement needs to be wrapped in curly brackets, and the `return` keyword should be deleted from the beginning of the return expression in your map function, as it's expecting an expression, not a return statement. Unless you wrap the return statement in curly brackets too.

Comment: Also, React will not like your for-loop inside of the returned jsx. That should be replaced with another array.map, but it depends on the data type of `product`. You could also move the for-loop to outside the return statement of the `Center` functional component.

Comment: @AndrewFink ah, yes, how careless of me. Thanks! Should have double read it before I copy and paste it from the question. Yeah I am waiting for the OP to post a sample of how products look like, before I edit it to use `Array.map()`.